# Разница между clearTimeout и clearInterval

Tags: javascript, timeout

#### Описание

Есть функции `setTimeout()` и `setInterval()` запускающие счетчики, да? И для каждого из них есть функция удаляющий счетчик - `clearTimeout()` и `clearInterval()`.
Только что узнал, что счетчики `setTimeout()` можно спокойно остановить с помощью `clearInterval()`, так же как и счетчики `setInterval()` с помощью `clearTimeout()`.

```js
clearInterval(setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`Timeout still works!`);
}, 0));
clearTimeout(setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`Interval still works!`);
}, 0));
```

#### Вопрос

Тогда какой смысл создать два одинаковых функций? Или же если они не одинаковые, в чем их разница?

Comment: Скорее всего делались под дальнейшее развитие. Хотя по описанию это две одинаковых фукнции, которые создают счетчики в одном пространстве имен браузера(timers), с разницей лишь в том, что у интервала передается флаг повтора = true, а у таймаута false. Т.к. пространстро счетчиков одно, то и удалить таймер может любой clear*

Comment: @SwaD а дальнейшего развития теперь не будет, потому что это сломает обратную совместимость) И с какой целью так сделали изначально, всё равно не очень понятно

Comment: @SwaD тоже так думал, но решил спросить. Может кто знает такое микроскопически тонкое различие. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Сейча в [документации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers) написано - что это одно и тоже. А чем руководствовались создатели этих фукнций, наверное, уже не узнаем

Comment: @eccs0103 а почему вы отметили галочкой ответ, который не отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @andreymal спросил я про разницу. Под ответом в комментариях вроде отвечающий пояснил.

Comment: @eccs0103 не знаю где вы там увидели пояснения, я там вижу лишь небылицы, которые противоречат реальности

Comment: @andreymal хорошо. Подождем доказательств отвечающего.

Comment: Вообще, если я правильно интерпретирую [спецификацию](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps), она формально не запрещает переиспользовать id — однако это подразумевает, что даже один и тот же `setTimeout` теоретически имеет право возвращающиеся повторяющиеся id, и упоминаемые в ответе «непредсказуемые последствия» могут случиться даже если использовать один только `clearTimeout`. На практике все протестированные мной актуальные реализации (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) используют счётчик, что полностью исключает возможность повторения id

Comment: («имеет право возвращающиеся» → «имеет право возвращать», поздно заметил опечатку)